# Combining multiple keyups into single event to reduce number of ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `keyup` event on a search box that produces suggestions by fetching data from db. It is working fine. But the problem arises when i press keyboard buttons quickly and for every `keyup` event it gets me the result which produce duplicates.

I tried using

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    setTimeout(getLocationFromDb, 1000);
});
```

But that still is producing same result (sending request to server for every `keyup` event).

I was looking for solutions but couldn't find one. Thanks for help.

**EDIT**
I am clearing the results `beforeSend` and appending the results in `success`.

Comment: Do you have any condition to detect whether you need to send ajax request?

Comment: you might wanna check the length of variable before sending the ajax request..like if(var.length>3) { //ajax request }

Comment: Yes its like if the query is empty don't send request. Just that!

Comment: The length must not be the issue, i should be able to see few of the results relating to that character to keep the hopes up.

Comment: Also increasing the length is not the problem, it will still send the requests after the query is > 3 in length and cause the same problem!

Comment: WOrkign on a solution, just give me some minute to create a fiddle ;)

Comment: I am using `append` to show the results, but that should not be the issue cause i don't want to loose other html stuff by using `html` for displaying on success. Let me add my getLocationFromDb method too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach isn't that bad - just make sure to clear all old timouts before setting a new one. You of course have to store the timeout somwhere - you could, for example, create a variable inside a closure.

This code only calls your callback when there was no new input for 1 second:

```
$("#search").on("keyup", (function () {
    var timeout;
    return function (e) {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = window.setTimeout(getLocationFromDb, 1000);
    }
})());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uq4x9/

Comment: Hah.. I was thinking of `clearTimeout` before but thought that timeouts are just wrong way to go.

Comment: There is, BTW, a small chance that after the calback is called, a new timeout is immediately set. To avoid this, you could clear all timeouts at the start of your callback, too - this of course means you havte to store the timeout elswhere, where the callback has access to or, alternatively, define that callback directly inside that closure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean variable to detect if ajax call is finished already before send new

```
var isAjaxSent = false;
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
   isAjaxSent = true;
   setTimeout(getLocationFromDb, 1000);
});

function getLocationFromDb( .... ) {
    if (!isAjaxSent) {
        //body of function
        // in ajax success function set isAjaxSent to false
    }
}
```